# what "font size" measurement should i use in titanium?

Tags: android, ios, titanium

Given that it is for both android and ios devices, and given that i'd like the screens to be pretty consistent across different screen sizes/resolutions?

I'm using font-size right now, but there is a massive disparity between what the android emulator shows and what an actual android device displays.

Comment: The added complexity for the Android emulator is that you can choose to display it pixel-for-pixel (in which case it's _not_ the same pixel density as the device, and _cannot_ be used for font size testing), or scaled to approximately the device's physical size (in which case text probably looks way worse). The iOS Simulator defaults to pixel-for-pixel, but can be scaled to 50% or 75% (so that a retina iPad will fit on your Mac's display).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so my question (now fixed) was a bit... wrong? I noted that i was using `fontSize` without really specifying what that meant.

I really should have noted  that  i was using `fontSize` *without* any units of size. Following on from Richard's suggestion, i'm using the units "sp", so for example:

font: {fontSize: '14sp'}

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can you without any measurement (dpi or px). this is working. bye the way you also you with (dpi or px) on your requirement.

```
var name    =   Ti.UI.createLabel({
    backgroundColor : "#e3e3e3",
    text        : data_ary[z].name,
    height      : "40",
    left        : "70",
    width       : "auto",
    color       : "#2c2c2c",
    font        : {fontSize : 18,fontWeight: "bold"},
});
```